# when i click button, my link's href lose information

Tags: jquery, get

I have a basic search page, when i enter some words on textbox, founded records are shown bottom of the textbox.Every record has a link like this : 
`www.blabla.com/record.php/record_id=9` .So in the record page i get the record id, and show record information. In same page,when i click button i need to do some works on jquery but i cannot because when i click and jquery works,the link returns `www.blabla.com/record.php` and `$_GET["record_id"]` give error.I need to use get method, so i should solve how can i hold record_id or how can i make not lose record_id when i click button ?

(I actually tried some solutions with sessions,but i can't get it)

> page : record.php/record_id=9

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".ekle").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function(event) {
      $("#formnot").append('<input type="text" />');

    });
  });

});



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="" id="formnot">
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ekle" value="<?php echo $dosya_id; ?>">Yeni Not Ekle</button>
  </td>
</form>
```

> page:search.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    // Icon Click Focus
    $('div.icon').click(function(){
        $('input#search').focus();
    });

    // Live Search
    // On Search Submit and Get Results
    function search() {
        var query_value = $('input#search').val();
        $('b#search-string').text(query_value);
        if(query_value !== ''){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search.php",
                data: { query: query_value },
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("ul#results").html(html);
                }
            });
        }return false;    
    }


    $("input#search").live("keyup", function(e) {
        // Set Timeout
        clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

        // Set Search String
        var search_string = $(this).val();

        // Do Search
        if (search_string == '') {
            $("ul#results").fadeOut();
            $('h4#results-text').fadeOut();
        }else{
            $("ul#results").fadeIn();
            $('h4#results-text').fadeIn();
            $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
        };
    });

});
```

> page:search.php

```
$html = '';
$html .= '<li class="result">';
$html .= '<a href="urlString">';
$html .= '<h3>nameString</h3>';
$html .= '<h4>functionString</h4>';
$html .= '<h4>displayMail</h4>';
$html .= '<h4>displayTc</h4>';
$html .= '<h4>display_durum</h4>';
$html .= '</a>';
$html .= '</li>';

// Get Search
$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
$search_string = $tutorial_db->real_escape_string($search_string);

// Check Length More Than One Character
if (strlen($search_string) >= 1 && $search_string !== ' ') {
    // Build Query
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM musteri WHERE musteri_adi LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" OR musteri_telefon LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"  OR musteri_mail LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" 
    OR musteri_tcno LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"  OR  musteri_pasaport LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"    ';

    // Do Search
    $result = $tutorial_db->query($query);
    while($results = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $result_array[] = $results;
    }

    // Check If We Have Results
    if (isset($result_array)) {
        foreach ($result_array as $result) {

            // Format Output Strings And Hightlight Matches
            $display_name = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['musteri_adi']);
            $display_function = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>",$result['musteri_telefon']) ;
            $display_url = 'record.php?record_id='.urlencode($result['record_id']);
            $display_mail = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['musteri_mail']);
            $display_tcno = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['musteri_tcno']);
            $display_durum = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['musteri_durum']);

            // Insert Name
            $output = str_replace('nameString', $display_name, $html);

            // Insert Function
            $output = str_replace('functionString', $display_function, $output);

            // Insert URL
            $output = str_replace('urlString', $display_url, $output);  

            $output = str_replace('displayMail', $display_mail, $output);

            $output = str_replace('displayTc', $display_tcno, $output);

            if($display_durum=='aktif')
            {
                $display_durum='<font color="#01DF01">Aktif</font>';

            }
            else if($display_durum=='pasif')
            {
                $display_durum='<font color="#FF0000">Pasif</font>';

            }   

            $output = str_replace('display_durum', $display_durum,$output);
            // Output
            echo($output);
        }
    }else{

        // Format No Results Output
        $output = str_replace('urlString', 'javascript:void(0);', $html);
        $output = str_replace('nameString', '<b>Sonuç Bulunamadı .</b>', $output);
        $output = str_replace('functionString', '<a href="yenikayit.php">Yeni Kayıt Ekle</a>', $output);
        $output = str_replace('displayMail', '', $output);
        $output = str_replace('displayTc', '', $output);
        $output = str_replace('display_durum', '', $output);

        // Output
        echo($output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share us your code snippets in detail.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="www.blabla.com" method="post" id="formnot">
  <input type="hidden" name="record_id" value="<?php echo $dosya_id; ?>">
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ekle">Yeni Not Ekle</button>
  </td>
</form>
```

Try method="post" and $_POST[] instead or method="get" and $_GET[]

Comment: I added all codes, i have a link and when i click that i go to record.php?record_id . I don't know how to post with a clicking a link

Comment: the url when submitted would be www.blabla.com?record_id=9 unless your $dosya_id or $result['record_id'] is NULL or empty or NaN